# Get the class from selected file

Tags: eclipse, class, plugins, get, selected

I developing Eclipse plugin and I would like to iterate all superclass of the selected subclass, because I searching a known superclass.

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
final ISelection currentSelection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
if (currentSelection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) currentSelection;
            obj = selection.getFirstElement();
            if (obj instanceof IResource) {
                file = (IFile) ((IResource) obj).getAdapter(IFile.class);
            } else if (obj instanceof IJavaElement) {
                file = (IFile) ((IJavaElement) obj).getResource().getAdapter(IFile.class);
            }
        } else if (currentSelection instanceof TextSelection) {
            final IEditorInput activeEditorInput = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditorInput(event);
            file = (IFile) activeEditorInput.getAdapter(IFile.class);
        }
}
```

The `file` variable is a file that contains the class. I would like to get the class from the selected item.  After get the Class I would use

```
getSuperclass()
```

method while I found the right superclass.

Comment: Look at the [JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: if the selected item is a class you can easily get it by using selectedElement instanceof ICompilationUnit

Comment: Thanks, but I solved other. :)